# Split pandas dataframe nested list into new named columns

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) of the form:

```
name alias col3
mark david ['3109892828','email@john.com','123 main st']
john twixt ['5468392873','email@twix.com','345 grand st']
```

What is a concise way to split col3 into new, named columns? (perhaps using lambda and apply)

Answer (score 2):

You could apply a join to the list elements to make a comma separated string and then call the vectorised [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) with `expand=True` to create the new columns:

```
In [12]:
df[['UserID', 'email', 'address']] = df['col3'].apply(','.join).str.split(expand=True)
df

Out[12]:
   alias                                        col3  name  \
0  david   [3109892828, email@john.com, 123 main st]  mark   
1  twixt  [5468392873, email@twix.com, 345 grand st]  john   

                          UserID  email address  
0  3109892828,email@john.com,123   main      st  
1  5468392873,email@twix.com,345  grand      st
```

A cleaner method would be to apply the `pd.Series` ctor which will turn each list into a Series:

```
In [15]:
df[['UserID', 'email', 'address']] = df['col3'].apply(pd.Series)
df

Out[15]:
   alias                                        col3  name      UserID  \
0  david   [3109892828, email@john.com, 123 main st]  mark  3109892828   
1  twixt  [5468392873, email@twix.com, 345 grand st]  john  5468392873   

            email       address  
0  email@john.com   123 main st  
1  email@twix.com  345 grand st
```

Comment: This might cause difficulties if the "columns" legitimately contain commas... Maybe something like `df[['id', 'email', 'address']] = df.col3.apply(pd.Series)` then drop `col3` ?

Comment: Hmm. True but unless the OP has this in their data I did not consider it an issue, still applying the Series ctor is cleaner and enough here, will update, thanks

Comment: normally, this would be a great solution, but it seems my array does not have the same number of columns for each row.. so what can I do if the nested list does not have the same number of fields per record? Here is the error I get: ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: Here is the error I get when using split(): TypeError: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'

Comment: Well with inconsistent number of elements then you can't create the new columns unless the length is the same, what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: @EdChum - I thought the version might be a problem, so I just upgraded to 0.16.2 from 0.15.2, but I get the same TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. It includes a bit of scrubbing of the raw file, and a conversion to a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
with open('/path/to/file', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

data = map(lambda x: x.split('}'), data)
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_dfn = data_df.transpose()
data_new = data_dfn[0].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('[,{)').replace("'","").split(','))

s = pd.DataFrame(data_new)
d = dict(data_new)
D = pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in d.iteritems() ]))
D = D.transpose()
```